# Can I return RuntimeBeanReference in Spring parser?

Tags: java, spring

I would like to create a parser for element . 
He looks like

```
<custom-element ref="beanName"/>
```

I want something like this -

```
public class CustomElementDefinitionParser implements BeanDefinitionParser{
    @Override
    public BeanDefinition parse(Element element, ParserContext parserContext) {
        String refName = element.getAttribute("ref");
        if(!refName.isEmpty()){
            return ?????;
        }else
            throw new RuntimeException("Must have 'ref' attribute!!");
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to return BeanDefinition, if I know only name of bean(it is 'ref' attribute).

I know, that I can make `RuntimeBeanReference` with using only bean name, but is there a way to return it in parser?

Answer (score 1):

The `BeanDefinition` you return should be a definition of the bean that is represented by your custom element, which can be created using a [`org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionBuilder.html).  The ref should, I assume, be either a constructor argument or property of that bean.

If you are simply trying to performing some processing on the bean refered to by ref then you should use a [`org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) to do this.

Comment: Could you show me an example - how to use it in my situation? Please

Comment: Without knowing more specifically what you're trying to achieve it's hard to give an example.